# How to change php file to upload images as multipart instead of strings?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm using android app to upload images to server, i want to change my php file from uploading images as strings to multi-part.

I want to change because i have some problem that i can't upload more than 700KB of images on the server through my android application and i tried everything but still the same problem, someone advised me to change to multi-part because of better functionality.

So, could you help me to change this file to fit multi-part, please?

```
<?php 
include "connection.php.php";

$sucess = 105;
$fail = 107;

$images = $_POST['sales_images']; //images list[]
$image_name = $_POST['sales_images_names']; //images_names list[]


$bedroom = $_POST['bedroom'];
$bathroom = $_POST['bathroom'];
$size = $_POST['size'];

$ref = $_POST['ref'];

$hotDeal = $_POST['hotDeal'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `sale`(`ref`, `sqm`, `avaliable`, `bedroom`, `bathroom`, `hot_deal`) VALUES ('$ref','$size',1,'$bedroom','$bathroom',$hotDeal)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($result === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $con->insert_id;

    $length = count($images);

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $imageNow = time();
        $new_imageFilename = $imageNow . "_" . $image_name[$i];

        $sql6 = "INSERT INTO `sale_image`(`sale_id`, `img_url`) VALUES ('$last_id','$new_imageFilename')";
        $result6 = mysqli_query($con, $sql6);

        $binary=base64_decode($images[$i]);
        $file = fopen('files/sales/' . $new_imageFilename, 'wb');
        fwrite($file, $binary);
        fclose($file);      
    }

    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$jsonResult = '{"state":';
if($result){
    $jsonResult.= $sucess;
}else {
    $jsonResult.= $fail;
}
$jsonResult .="}";
print_r($jsonResult);
?>
```

Comment: Format your POST as a `multipart/form-data` as described here: https://ec.haxx.se/http-multipart.html If you can find yourself a MIME encoding library for Android that will probably take care of much of the complexity. Better yet, find yourself an Android lib that does HTTP properly period. After that your PHP code becomes much simpler, for which you can just refer to the [relevant documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you so much.